# TELEGRAF TAIL : Creating parser: Invalid data format: Grok

Tags: tail, telegraf

I am using Telegraf to get logs information from specific logs with Hexa data.

I am using tail but i still to get the same error : Invalid data format: Grok.

My log look like this :

```
18/08/2022 21:04:23 01 41 7B 00 04 14 00 00 00 FD AB
```

and a configuration for tail in telegraf :

```
 [[inputs.tail]]
    files = ["/mnt/cle/*a.*.log"]
    from_beginning = true
    max_undelivered_lines = 300
    character_encoding = "utf-8"
    data_format = "Grok"
    grok_patterns = ['%{DATE_EU:date} %{TIME:time} %{WORD:my1id} %{WORD:my2id} %{BASE16NUM:01hexa} %{BASE16NUM:02hexa} %{BASE16NUM:03hexa} %{BASE16NUM:04hexa} %{BASE16NUM:05hexa} %{BASE16NUM:06hexa} %{BASE16NUM:07hexa} %{BASE16NUM:08hexa} %{BASE16NUM:09hexa} %{BASE16NUM:10hexa} %{BASE16NUM:11hexa}']
```

I try also for grok_patterns :

```
grok_patterns = ['%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp:ts-"2006/01/02 15:04:05"} %{WORD:MRIid} %{WORD:OPUid} %{WORD:01hexa} %{WORD:02hexa} %{WORD:03hexa} %{WORD:04hexa} %{WORD:05hexa} %{WORD:06hexa} %{WORD:07hexa} %{WORD:08hexa} %{WORD:09hexa} %{WORD:10hexa} %{WORD:11hexa}']
```

Also, i would like to convert my hexa data to decimal and apply a conversion formula.
And to complicate things, i vould like to join two pattern before converting data.

I have used this link for the grok_patterns : [Grok input data format](https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.22/data_formats/input/grok/)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and below my correction :

```
   grok_patterns = ['%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp:ts-"2006-01-02 15:04:05"} %{WORD:MATid} %{WORD:OPUid}']
   grok_custom_patterns = '''
     '''
```

With this log :

```
2022-08-19 17:21:18 MAT01 OPU30
2022-08-19 17:21:19 MAT01 OPU30
```

However, I'm still looking to convert my hexa data to decimal and apply a conversion formula. And to complicate things, i vould like to join two pattern before converting data.